# WPF DataGrid Hide Rows on Condition Causes App to be Unresponsive

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, async-await

I have a `DataGrid` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection`.  Based on a condition any given row should be hidden.  This can be turned on or off by the user.  The problem is that when there is a large number of rows in the DataGrid hiding and un-hiding rows can make the application unresponsive for a time.

I am doing the hide/un-hide with a `DataGrid.RowStyle` like this;

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowRow}"  Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

For ease of example lets say there is a switch that changes all rows in the `ObservableCollection` `ShowRow` from 0 to 1 like this;

```
private async void Switch_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var x in MyCollection)
    {
        x.ShowAll = 0;
    }
}

private async void Switch_UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var x in MyCollection)
    {
        x.ShowAll = 1;
    }
}
```

This works great for a small number of rows being changed.  However if there is a large number of rows being (say 1,000 and over) the application becomes unresponsive.  Figuring I can solve this with an `await` command like this;

```
private async void Switch_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var upd = Task.Run(() => UpdateShowAll());
    await upd;
}

private async void UpdateShowAll(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var x in MyCollection)
    {
        x.ShowAll = 0;
    }
}
```

Problem is that method `UpdateShowAll` is finished long before the `DataGrid.RowStyle` gets updated.  What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `Show` and `Collapse` on such a large scale is pretty resource intensive. It will be MUCH better to do all of your data handling on the back end. You may want to bind your items to an `ICollectionView` and filter them accordingly.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

private ICollectionView cvs { get; set; }
public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cvs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyCollection);
    MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = cvs;
    cvs.Filter = FilterOut;

}

private bool FilterOut(object input)
{

    MyCollectionObject obj = (input as MyCollectionObject);

    return (obj.ShowAll == 1);

}
```